# Copy .SpecialCells(xlCellYypeVisible)

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

Can any tell me why this code is also copying none visible data.

```
    Sub Copy ()
    Range(ActiveCell,ActiveCell.Offset(LIRS_Required,7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible, xlTextValues).Copy
    End Sub
```

I only want the visible data after the table has filtered.

Regards

Comment: It works for me. Though if the table is filtered a straight `Copy` should only copy visible cells anyway. Also, `xlTextValues` has no effect combined with `xlCellTypeVisible`.

Comment: Is only seems to be copying 240 rows rather than the required 835. the number of rows required comes from cell ("K4") @Rory

Comment: Which cell is active when you run the code, what is the value of `LIRS_Required`, and what gets copied?

Comment: i have written a code that selects cell "A1" then offsets to the first visible visible cell (in this case cell "A4"), The value of LIRS_Required is 835 and rows are copied if they are still visible after the table is filtered. @Rory

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it as written, but you could start by removing the `, xlTextValues` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because .offset() don't skip over hidden cells.

try this workaround:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveCell.Resize(LIRS_Required + 1)
    While rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count < LIRS_Required + 1
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Count + LIRS_Required + 1 - rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count)
    Wend
    rng.Resize(, 7 + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You @KS Sheon works great now. How can i stop it from copying 1 extra?

Comment: Welcome! Just remove the `+1` from the three `LIRS_Required + 1`. I put in the `+1` because, for instance, `Range([A1], [A1].Offset(3,0))` is the same as `Range([A1]).Resize(4,1)`.

Comment: Perfect now. This has now just saved me about 30 minutes a day Filtering and copying manually. Thanks @KS Sheon